# Linearity of a function $f$ when its codomain has dimension $K>1$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

My question is about the meaning of linearity of a function $f$ when its [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain)  has dimension $K>1$. Let me be more clear with an example.

Suppose I have a function $f:\Theta\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. In this example $K=2$.

Assume that for any $\theta\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
\theta_1\\
\theta_2\\
\theta_3
\end{pmatrix}\in \Theta$, $$f(\theta)\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}
\theta_1\\
\theta_2\\
\theta_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\theta_1\\
\theta_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Each of the two components of $f$ is linear in $\theta$. Does this mean that $f$ is linear in $\theta$?

Comment: [The definition of linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_linear_map) is not restricted to having a codomain of dimension $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, [the definition of linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_linear_map) is not restricted to having a codomain of dimension $1$.

> A function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is *linear* if, for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, it satisfies
>   $$
> f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y).\tag{$\ast$}
> $$

Your example *is* linear as a map $\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$. To see this, write $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ as
$$
x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}), \qquad y = (y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}).
$$
Then
$$
x + y = (x_{1} + y_{1}, x_{2} + y_{2}, x_{3} + y_{3}).
$$
By definition
$$
f(x) = f(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) = (x_{1}, x_{2}),\qquad f(y) = f(y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}) = (y_{1}, y_{2})
$$
so that
$$
f(x) + f(y) = (x_{1} + y_{1}, x_{2} + y_{2}) = f(x + y).
$$
Hence $f$ is linear.

To check whether your $f$ is linear as a map $\Theta \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, you will do similar steps.

---

Suppose $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $f\colon \Theta \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

If either $x \notin \Theta$ or $y \notin \Theta$, then the corresponding $f(x)$ or $f(y)$ do not exist. Thus we cannot verify whether $(\ast)$ holds or not, so it doesn't make sense to call $f$ linear.

If $x, y \in \Theta$ but $x+y \notin \Theta$, then we also cannot verify whether $(\ast)$ holds or not, so again it doesn't make sense to call $f$ linear.

Thus my comment regarding surjectivity is rendered moot. However, to explain this more clearly, suppose that $f$ is indeed surjective. Then $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a vector space so
$$
f(x) + f(y) = a
$$
for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. By the surjectivity of $f$ there exists some $z \in \Theta$ such that $f(z) = a$, so
$$
f(x) + f(y) = f(z).
$$
But $z \neq x + y$ since $z \in \Theta$ and $x + y \notin \Theta$. Thus $f(x) + f(y)$ is equal to the image of something in $\Theta$ that is not the sum of $x$ and $y$. This contradicts what we would expect if $f$ were linear.

I think it's best to summarise this the following way:

> Unless $x+y \in \Theta$ for every $x, y \in \Theta$, we cannot determine whether $(\ast)$ holds or not. Thus we cannot call $f: \Theta \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ linear.

Comment: Thanks. Consider $\Theta\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $f: \Theta\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. What if $x\in \Theta$, $y\in \Theta$ but $x+y\notin \Theta$? Or what if $x\notin \Theta$, $y\notin \Theta$ but $x+y\in \Theta$?

Comment: The notation of linearity needs to be amended in that case since it is no longer a map between vector spaces. You could call it linear if $(\ast)$ holds for all $x, y \in \Theta$ such that $x + y \in \Theta$. However, if your function is surjective then this would be improper for if $x, y \in \Theta$ but $x + y \notin \Theta$, then $f(x) + f(y) = f(z)$ for some $z \in \Theta$ with $z \neq x + y$. This is clearly not what one would expect if $f$ is linear.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain better your last comment about surjectivity?

Comment: Sure, what do you not fully understand?

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand your claim. Could you reformulate it by completing this sentence:  if $f$ is surjective (i.e., for every $r\in \mathbb{R}^2$ there exists $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \Theta$ such that $r=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$), then ... ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think it's best to forget about the surjective case (though I have included it anyway).

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand your two claims in the new part ending with "so it doesn't make sense to call $f$ linear". This is in contrast with what you wrote in the comments below. In the comments below you wrote that to verify that $f$ is linear we should focus only on the $x,y$ such that $x\in \Theta, y\in \Theta, x+y\in \Theta$. In other words, even if there are $x,y$ such that $x\in \Theta$, $y\in \Theta$ but $x+y\notin \Theta$ or viceversa, we could still have that $f$ is linear. In the modified answer you wrote instead the opposite.

Comment: Ah, yes, I wrote that as an aside to say that one _could_ alter the definition of linear to only consider that case, but I did not do this in my answer.